# Является ли решение задачи верным?

Tags: алгоритм, проектирование, олимпиада

В общем, в одной книжке нашёл задачу, но там даётся не совсем эффективное относительно моего решение.

Условие: есть N людей, их веса содержатся в массиве weight. Есть грузоподъёмность лифта X. Необходимо найти минимальное количество поездок, необходимое для перевозки всех людей.

Моё решение: расположим все веса в порядке убывания (это не будет узким местом алгоритма), и составим очередь. Далее будем прогонять эту очередь от начала до конца следующим образом. Сначала в лифт идёт самый тяжёлый (первый), затем если первый человек в очереди вмещается, то мы помещаем его в лифт и проверяем очередь дальше, в противном случае отправляем его в конец очереди. Когда очередь полностью проверена, лифт отправляется и всё сначала. То есть лифт каждый раз заполняется по максимуму. Можно ли подобрать пример, когда этот способ не сработает?

Comment: Это самая обычная задача линейного раскроя. И в Вашем решении только одна фраза верна - "лифт каждый раз заполняется по максимуму", а вот достигнуть этого Вы описанным способом не сможете, что наглядно показал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1158541/229437) от [default locale](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178556/default-locale)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нет, жадный алгоритм не всегда будет приводить к оптимальному решению.

Контрпример:
X = 9
N = 6
weight = {5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}

Ваше решение: {5, 3}, {3, 3, 2}, {2} — три поездки.
Оптимальное решение: {5, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3} — две поездки.